# Regex to get word started with # in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, eval

I have a problem replace certain words started with `#`. I have the following code

```
var x="#google",
eval("var pattern = /" + '\\b' + x + '\\b');
txt.replace(pattern,"MyNewWord");
```

when I use the following code it works fine

```
var x="google",
eval("var pattern = /" + '\\b' + x + '\\b');
txt.replace(pattern,"MyNewWord");
```

it works fine

any suggestion how  to make the first part of code working

ps. I use `eval` because `x` will be a user input.

Comment: Don't `eval()` these! Use `new RegExp('\\b' + x + '\\b')`

Comment: "because x will be a user input" is a reason **not** to use `eval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\b` represents a boundary between a "word" character (letter, digit, or underscore) and a "non-word" character (anything else). `#` is a non-word character, so `\b#` means "a `#` that *is* preceded by a word character" — which is not at all what you want. If anything, you want something more like `\B#`; `\B` is a *non*-boundary, so `\B#` means "a `#` that is *not* preceded by a word character".

I'm guessing that you want your words to be separated by whitespace, instead of by a programming-language concept of what makes something a "word" character or a "non-word" character; for that, you could write:

```
var x = '#google';    // or 'google'
var pattern = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + x);
var result = txt.replace(pattern, '$1' + 'MyNewWord');
```

---

**Edited to add:** If `x` is really supposed to be a literal string, not a regex at all, then you should "quote" all of the special characters in it, with a backslash. You can do that by writing this:

```
var x = '#google';  // or 'google' or '$google' or whatever
var quotedX = x.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '\\$&');
var pattern = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + quotedX);
var result = txt.replace(pattern, '$1' + 'MyNewWord');
```

Comment: Hello Ruakh  your code works perfect if  x="#google" or x="?google"
but if x = "$google"  it doesnt work have you got any idea ?

Comment: @NavinHarishK: That's because `$` has a special meaning in regular expressions -- it means "end of string" -- so the regex `/(^|\s)$google/` is never matched by anything. To match an actual dollar sign, you'd have to "quote" it with a backslash: `/(^|\s)\$google/`. If you're expecting `x` to be a literal string, and you want to find occurrences of *exactly* it, then you'd want to start by quoting all of its special characters. Here, I'll update my answer . . .

Answer (score 1):

Make you patter something like this:

```
/(#)?\w*/
```

Comment: and where to put my variable x ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a Regular Expression, try this instead of eval:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(x);
```

Btw the line:

```
eval("var pattern = /" + '\\b' + x + '\\b');
```

will make an error because of no enclose pattern, should be :

```
eval("var pattern = /" + '\\b' + x + '\\b/');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

`var x = "#google";`

`x.match(/^\#/);`

Comment: I need to replace every google  (WORD) starts with # for example 

I don't want to replace google  norgoogle  I want to replace only #google